# Error "Cannot read properties of undefined" when I add a new comment

Tags: next.js, nestjs, undefined

Error that appears when adding a comment

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullName')

Source
components\Comment\index.tsx (53:50) @ fullName

  51 | <div className={styles.comment}>
  52 |   <div className={styles.userInfo}>
> 53 |     <Avatar style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>{user.fullName[0]}</Avatar>
     |                                              ^
  54 |     <b>{user.fullName}</b>
  55 |     <span>{createdAt}</span>
  56 |   </div>
```

After I refresh the page the comment I created appears on the page and is displayed correctly, with the avatar name. I can delete it, but I can't determine why the error appears when creating it

code of the form for adding a comment

```
import React from 'react'
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input'
import styles from './AddCommentForm.module.scss'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Api } from '../../utils/api'
import { CommentItem } from '../../utils/api/types'

interface AddCommentFormProps {
  postId: number
  onSuccessAdd: (obj: CommentItem) => void
}

export const AddCommentForm: React.FC<AddCommentFormProps> = ({ postId, onSuccessAdd }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')

  const onAddComment = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const comment = await Api().comment.create({
        postId,
        text,
      })
      onSuccessAdd(comment)
      setClicked(false)
      setText('')
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn('Add comment', err)
      alert('Ошибка при отправке комментария')
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.form}>
      <Input
        disabled={isLoading}
        onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
        value={text}
        onFocus={() => setClicked(true)}
        minRows={clicked ? 5 : 1}
        classes={{ root: styles.fieldRoot }}
        placeholder='Написать комментарий...'
        fullWidth
        multiline
      />
      {clicked && (
        <Button
          disabled={isLoading}
          onClick={onAddComment}
          className={styles.addButton}
          variant='contained'
          color='primary'
        >
          Опубликовать
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

comment form code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography, IconButton, MenuItem, Menu, Avatar } from '@material-ui/core'
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHorizOutlined'

import styles from './Comment.module.scss'
import { ResponseUser } from '../../utils/api/types'
import { Api } from '../../utils/api'

interface CommentPostProps {
  id: number
  user: ResponseUser
  text: string
  createdAt: string
  currentUserId: number
  onRemove: (id: number) => void
}

export const Comment: React.FC<CommentPostProps> = ({
  id,
  user,
  text,
  createdAt,
  currentUserId,
  onRemove,
}) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null)

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  const handleClickRemove = async () => {
    if (window.confirm('Удалить комментарий?')) {
      try {
        await Api().comment.remove(id)
        onRemove(id)
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn('Error remove comment', err)
        alert('Не удалось удалить комментарий')
      } finally {
        handleClose()
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.comment}>
      <div className={styles.userInfo}>
        <Avatar style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>{user.fullName[0]}</Avatar>
        <b>{user.fullName}</b>
        <span>{createdAt}</span>
      </div>
      <Typography className={styles.text}>{text}</Typography>
      {user.id === currentUserId && (
        <>
          <span className={styles.replyBtn}>Ответить</span>
          <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
            <MoreIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            elevation={2}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
            keepMounted
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClickRemove}>Удалить</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Редактировать</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

if you refresh the page later, the new comment will be displayed on the page.

Checked all props paths and links to the backend

Answer (score 0):

try this, add a "?" in front of the item, e.g item.name, change it to item?.name

Comment: I tried this method, the error does not appear, but the comment does too, to see it you need to refresh the page

Comment: Could you show us how you are passing the props from the parent to the comment component?

Comment: with types.ts ```.export type ResponseUser = {
  createdAt: string
  email: string
  fullName: string
  id: number
  commentsCount?: number
  token: string
  updatedAt: string
}```